# "Issue with Inverting Binary Tree using Python's Swap Operation"

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, swap

last night I was solving some BST problems on LeetCode, and I encountered a minor issue with this problem: Invert Binary Tree. (https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/description/)

As I was solving it recursively and using Python's swap operation, I noticed a small problem.

My first solution was this:

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def invertTree(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        if not root:
            return None


        root.left, root.right = self.invertTree(root.right), self.invertTree(root.left)

        return root
```

And it was accepted, but when I try using the swap with a different approach like this:

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def invertTree(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        if not root:
            return None


        root.left= self.invertTree(root.right)
        root.right =  self.invertTree(root.left)

        return root
```

It is not accepted, and I can't figure out why ˙◠˙

So can somebody help me knowing the main differences between a swap like this and this:

```py
#Swap 1
root.left, root.right = self.invertTree(root.right), self.invertTree(root.left)
#Swap 2
        root.left= self.invertTree(root.right)
        root.right =  self.invertTree(root.left)
```

Comment: In "swap 1" the right side of the equal sign is fully evaluated before any changes (assignments) to the left side happen.

Comment: In the second line of swap 2, `root.left` isn't the original value of `root.left`: it's the value after executing line 1 (`root.left = self.invertTree(root.right)`)